# iDrac Express ethernet port doesnt look to be working

Tags: dell, drac

I got a Dell r620 server with iDrac 7 express.
It has a dedicated NIC for the DRAC. If I connect any cable to it and to the router, the LED doesn't turn on, like when there is no physical connection.

The only way I found do iDRAC to work, was to user another NIC, than the dedicated one.

Is this a software limitation of iDRAC express, or can it be a hardware failure?

Comment: did you set it up to use that nic in the config when bios posts or is it using a shared nic?

Comment: there is no option.

Answer (score 2):

This is a licensing restriction.  [Use of a dedicated NIC for iDRAC is not allowed for "express" iDRAC licenses](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20067892/download.aspx).

FYI, you configure (and chek your settings/licensing for) iDRAC through the Lifecycle Controller/Manager screen, not the BIOS settings screen, as iDRAC is actually an independant system from the server it is located on.